# Подскажите, как правильно через циклы пересобрать json

Tags: php, json

у меня есть 4 массива

```
$id = [2319,2320];
$url = ["/article-type/charter/","/article-type/destination/"];
$match_url = ["/article-type/charter","/article-type/destination"];
$position = [1748,1749];
```

и json

```
  $json = '
    {
      "id": 2317,
      "url": "/article-type/imperial/",
      "match_url": "/article-type/imperial",
      "match_data": {
        "source": {
          "flag_query": "exact",
          "flag_case": false,
          "flag_trailing": false,
          "flag_regex": false
        }
      },
      "action_code": 404,
      "action_type": "error",
      "action_data": "",
      "match_type": "url",
      "title": "",
      "hits": 0,
      "regex": false,
      "group_id": 1,
      "position": 1746,
      "last_access": "-",
      "enabled": true
    }';
```

Как я понимаю мы разбираем json в массив через `$array = json_decode($json, true);`
а как действовать дальше? По хорошему должно получить что-то подобное:

```
      $json = '
        {
          "id": 2319,
          "url": "/article-type/charter/",
          "match_url": "/article-type/charter",
          "match_data": {
            "source": {
              "flag_query": "exact",
              "flag_case": false,
              "flag_trailing": false,
              "flag_regex": false
            }
          },
          "action_code": 404,
          "action_type": "error",
          "action_data": "",
          "match_type": "url",
          "title": "",
          "hits": 0,
          "regex": false,
          "group_id": 1,
          "position": 1748,
          "last_access": "-",
          "enabled": true
        },
  {
          "id": 2320,
          "url": "/article-type/destination/",
          "match_url": "/article-type/destination",
          "match_data": {
            "source": {
              "flag_query": "exact",
              "flag_case": false,
              "flag_trailing": false,
              "flag_regex": false
            }
          },
          "action_code": 404,
          "action_type": "error",
          "action_data": "",
          "match_type": "url",
          "title": "",
          "hits": 0,
          "regex": false,
          "group_id": 1,
          "position": 1749,
          "last_access": "-",
          "enabled": true
        }';
```

и тд, смотря сколько элементов у нас было в массивах, подскажите как это можно реализовать пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = [2319,2320];
$url = ["/article-type/charter/","/article-type/destination/"];
$match_url = ["/article-type/charter","/article-type/destination"];
$position = [1748,1749];

$newArray = Array();

foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->id = $id[$k];
    $data->url = $url[$url];
    $data->match_url = $url[$match_url];
    $data->position = $url[$position];
   // other
    $newArray[] = $data;
}

$json = json_encode($newArray);
```

Писал прямо сюда, могут быть ошибки

Comment: Создание класса `stdClass` не обязательно, в json и так построено из объектов.

Comment: https://sun9-31.userapi.com/iJiB4HEMJigpHv39RfQDEFqTkhebsylv4iKDuQ/y9Rwe5QfbfA.jpg что-то пошло не так, пустые создаются

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть базовый Json, в который надо подставлять значения из массивов array_map и array_merge вам в помощь.
ваши исходные:

```
$json = '{"a":1,"url":"http://google.com"}';
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$id  = [2319,2320];
$url = ["/article-type/charter/","/article-type/destination/"];
$match_url = ["/article-type/charter","/article-type/destination"];
$position  = [1748,1749];
```

дальше ходите по массивам сливая их с начальным.

```
$result = array_map(function($id, $url, $match, $pos) use ($data){
            return array_merge($data, [
                'id' => $id,
                'url' => $url,
                'match_url' => $match,
                'position' => $pos]);
            }, $id, $url, $match_url, $position);
```

можете array_combine еще приделать

```
$result = array_map(function(...$values) use ($data){
              return array_merge($data,
                       array_combine(['id', 'url'....], $values));

         }, $id, $url, $match_url, $position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если `id` в списке `$id` совпадает с данными в `json`, то перезапишутся новые данные под этим `id`. 
Если нет, то будут добавляться данные в соответствии с примером:

```php
<?php
$id = [2319,2320];
$url = ["/article-type/charter/","/article-type/destination/"];
$match_url = ["/article-type/charter","/article-type/destination"];
$position = [1748,1749];

$json = '{
      "id": 2317,
      "url": "/article-type/imperial/",
      "match_url": "/article-type/imperial",
      "match_data": {
        "source": {
          "flag_query": "exact",
          "flag_case": false,
          "flag_trailing": false,
          "flag_regex": false
        }
      },
      "action_code": 404,
      "action_type": "error",
      "action_data": "",
      "match_type": "url",
      "title": "",
      "hits": 0,
      "regex": false,
      "group_id": 1,
      "position": 1746,
      "last_access": "-",
      "enabled": true
    }';

$array = json_decode($json, true);
$array1[] = $array;
foreach ($id as $key=>$item){
    $trig = 0;
    foreach ($array1 as $key1=>$item1) {
        if ($item == $item1['id']) {
            $trig = 0;
            $tempArr = $array1[$key1];
            $tempArr['id'] = $item;
            $tempArr['url'] = $url[$key];
            $tempArr['match_url'] = $match_url[$key];
            $tempArr['position'] = $position[$key];
            $array1[$key1] = $tempArr;
        } else {
            $trig = 1;
        }
    }
    if($trig == 1){
        $tempArr = $array1[0];
        $tempArr['id'] = $item;
        $tempArr['url'] = $url[$key];
        $tempArr['match_url'] = $match_url[$key];
        $tempArr['position'] = $position[$key];
        $array1[] = $tempArr;
    }
}
print_r($array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за подсказки, в итоге сделала вот так:

```
 $array = [];

    foreach($id as $index => $value) {
        $array[] = [
            'id' => $value,
            'url' => $url[$index],
            'match_url' => $match_url[$index],
            'match_data' => [
                'source' => [
                    'flag_query' => 'exact',
                    'flag_case' => false,
                    'flag_trailing' => false,
                    'flag_regex' => false
                ]
            ],
            'action_code' => 404,
            'action_type' => 'error',
            'action_data' => '',
            'match_type' => 'url',
            'title' => '',
            'hits' => 0,
            'regex' => false,
            'group_id' => 1,
            'position' => $position[$index],
            'last_access' => '-',
            'enabled' => true
        ];
    }
    $json = json_encode($array);
```